# SSH to server, execute commands and give control back to user

Tags: ssh

How can I do something like this with one ssh command:

```
echo << EOF
echo "Choose a file:" *
read f
rm -r "$f"
EOF | ssh user@host
```

I can use the `-tt` (yes *two* t's) with ssh to make ssh read from stdin, however it doesn't seem to allow `read` to work.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I don't get what your *"like this"*-command should be an example for..

Comment: @KarmaFusebox I added a better example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your example command correctly, this should work:

```
ssh user@host 'echo "Input something:"; read VAR; echo "Got: $VAR"'
```

That worked when "host" was a Slackware Linux server, and `ssh` ran on an Arch linux laptop. My shell on the Slackware server is zsh 4.2.6 (i486-slackware-linux-gnu).  Since `read` is a shell built-in, I imagine that choice of shell could have something to do with it.